# Adding new listview to current listview item?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm newbie on android development and developing a app to improve myself.
My app is listing students from db with ListView. I want to do"When I click the name of student, it will show the exam grades" I mean,I want to add new listview to onclick of list item.

Is it possible? What I need to do that(in xml and code),Do you have any code sample?

Comment: Do you want to show the second list view separately or as an expanding row of the first list?

Comment: I think you should start new activity, which will display grades for selected student.

Comment: @nspace yes, umair.ali this app for improving myself. I'm not looking for alternative solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the grades in a separate screen, I would suggest that you'll create a new `Activity` with it's own layout (that will contain the grades `ListView`) and when a click on a student name will occur you will start the new `Activity` to display grades (you can pass the student id on the new Activity `Intent`).

You can also consider using `Fragment`s. This way you will be able to change the layout to master-detail view (like in mail apps) easily on tablets. You can start by looking at [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial).

Comment: this is not a solucution which I search but thank you for contribution

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom listview (http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) Add a     listview to the listview item and set its visibility to GONE. When they click the item set the visibility to VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `OnItemClickListener` listener in the current `ListView` and when you get the click event query your data base for that particular student to get result. Once you have result you can load a new `ListView` in same Activity using Fragment or in a totally new fragment. (You are already using a `ListView`, so obviously you know how to load data in `ListView`).

Comment: I know how to load data, I can't understand you

Comment: All I meant was that when you have student information you want to show, you can show it the way you displayed the students in first ListView